# Sending data to socket (after reading) only occurs when the socket connection ends

Tags: sockets, haskell, networking

I'm trying to write a very basic webserver in Haskell. This is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network (withSocketsDo, listenOn, PortID(..))
import Network.Socket (Socket, accept, close, setSocketOption, SocketOption(..))
import Network.Socket.ByteString (send, sendAll, recv) 
import Control.Concurrent.Async (async)
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (unpack)
import Request

main = withSocketsDo $ do
  sock <- listenOn $ PortNumber 3000
  putStrLn "Listening on port 3000..."
  forever $ do
    (conn, _) <- accept sock
    async $ handleAccept conn

handleAccept :: Socket -> IO ()
handleAccept sock = do
  putStrLn $ "Connected!"
  rawReq <- recv sock 4096
  let req = parseRawRequest $ unpack rawReq -- returns Maybe Request
  putStrLn $ show req
  handleRequest sock req

handleRequest :: Socket -> Maybe Request -> IO ()
handleRequest sock Nothing = do
  putStrLn "Closing..."
handleRequest sock req = do
    sendAll sock "In handleRequest!" -- Doesn't appear until server is killed.
```

This is what I **expected** to happen:

1. Start server.
2. `"Listening on port 3000..."` is printed on server-side.
3. Do `curl localhost:3000`
4. `"Connected!"` is printed server-side.
5. The request is printed server-side.
6. `"In handleRequest!"` is printed.

What **actually** happens:

1. Start server.
2. `"Listening on port 3000..."` is printed on server-side.
3. Do `curl localhost:3000`
4. `"Connected!"` is printed server-side.
5. The request is printed server-side.
6. I wait patiently
7. I kill the server with `CTRL+C`
8. `"In handleRequest!"` prints client-side.

I suspect this has something to do with possible laziness in `recv`, although I use the value immediately afterwards (I parse the raw request into a `Request` type), so theoretically it should be evaluated.

If I put `sendAll sock "Yadda yadda` at the end of `handleAccept`, everything works fine. It's when I move this behaviour into a new function, `handleRequest`, that things go wonky.

Any thoughts? I'm new-ish to Haskell, so I'd appreciate any comments on the issue, or my code generally.

Cheers.

EDIT:

This is super weird! I "fixed" it, but I have no idea why this occurs.

This is the line that only appeared after I killed the server:

```
handleRequest sock req = do
    sendAll sock "In handleRequest!" -- Doesn't appear until server is killed.
```

If I intentionally close the socket *after* sending, it works:

```
handleRequest sock req = do
    sendAll sock "In handleRequest!" -- Now appears without killing the server
    close sock
```

So it sends when the connection is closed. This is consistent with previous behaviour, since the connection automatically closes when the server is killed.

Now for the confusing bit. If I replace it with:

```
handleRequest sock req = do
    sendAll sock "In handleRequest!\n" -- Works perfect
```

*This works without closing the connection!* It does what I expected, *just by adding a newline*. Why does this occur?

What on earth? Is it a printing problem with my terminal, not the code? (OSX iTerm2)

EDIT 2:

Was asked to provide the code for my `Request` module:

```
import Data.List (isInfixOf)
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

data RequestType = GET | PUT
  deriving Show

data Request =
    Request {
    reqType :: RequestType,
        path    :: String,
        options :: [(String, String)]
  } deriving Show

-- Turn a raw HTTP request into a request
-- object.
parseRawRequest :: String -> Maybe Request
parseRawRequest rawReq =
  Request <$> parseRawRequestType rawReq
            <*> parseRawRequestPath rawReq
                    <*> parseRawRequestOps  rawReq

-- Turn an (entire) raw HTTP request into just
-- the request type.
parseRawRequestType :: String -> Maybe RequestType
parseRawRequestType rawReq = 
    case typ of
    "GET" -> Just GET
    "PUT" -> Just PUT
    _     -> Nothing
  where typ = (head . words . head . lines) rawReq

-- Turn an (entire) raw HTTP request into just
-- the path.
parseRawRequestPath :: String -> Maybe String
parseRawRequestPath = Just . (!! 1) . words . head . lines

-- Turn an (entire) raw HTTP request into just
-- a lookup table of their options.
parseRawRequestOps :: String -> Maybe [(String, String)]
parseRawRequestOps rawReq = Just [("One", "Two")] -- Test impl
```

Comment: I have exactly zero clue about Hashell but it is evident that it is buffering socket output, and that you need to flush it before trying to read the response.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that, but I can't find anything in the docs: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.7.0.2/docs/Network-Socket-ByteString.html http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.7.0.2/docs/Network-Socket.html

Comment: Can you include the code for the Request import or let us know the name of the package?

Comment: @therewillbecode done, although I'd be surprised if that's where the issue is coming from, but who knows!

Comment: @haz Including all the code isn't only about where the bug is, it's about letting the people who are trying to help run the test and experiment without having to re-create your code.

Comment: Ah didn't think about that - cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have one answer and one suggestion.

The suggestion is for you to turn off the naggle algorithm after accept:

```
setSocketOption conn NoDelay 1
```

The answer is that your `sendAll` *is* sending data but curl is not printing it.  You can confirm this with netcat, for example.  I commented out your `Nothing` case so that no matter what I typed in netcat I was sure to get the `"In handleRequest!"` message back:

server:

```
% ghc so.hs && ./so
Listening on port 3000...
Connected!
Nothing
```

client:

```
% nc localhost 3000
test                  ; My input, with a newline
In handleRequest!     ; Printed out, no newline
```

Alternatively, you can use curl's `-N` option to disable buffering.

```
%  curl -N localhost:3000
In handleRequest!
```